# Return tabular structure from Web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, interop

Whats the best way to return a tabular structure from an ASP.NET (2.0) web service?

It should be inter-operable with Java, Iphone App or any other platform.

**EDIT:** By inter-operable I mean the other technology/client should be able to consume it or deserialize it to their native types, instead of parsing response XML.

Comment: I would also be interested in something like this.  I however find that anything involving JSON or XML serialization misses the point.  An object style annotation is too verbose.  You're basically repeating the column headers at every row.  I want something tabular so that I can transfer thousands of identical records as compactly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve interoperability by using SOAP/XML.
Here's a link to an [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/WSIntegration02132006041221AM/WSIntegration.aspx) that may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

[Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) by definition are interoperable because of, among other things, they rely on XML to pass data among heterogeneous systems.

That said, what needs to be defines is how the tabular structure is serialized in XML.

There are several ways to do it, everyone of them has its pros and cons.

- Implement the `ISerializable` interface
- Decorate the class with `[XmlSerializer]` attributes to control how the class is serialized as XML.
- etc, etc, etc...

Simply start to define how do you want to express your tabular data, and then work in how to implement.

Comment: You mean any tabular structure I send through a web service will be easily consumed by any client (java, php). How about returning DataTable or DataSet (.NET)? I don't think it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306134

I think on this page . you will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your preferred format. I'd suggest:

if XML then something like:

```
<table>
  <row1>
    <col1>data</col1>
    <col2>data</col2>
  </row1>
  <row2>
    <col1>data</col1>
    <col2>data</col2>
  </row2>
</table>
```

if JSON then something like:

```
[{"col1":"data","col2":"data"},{"col1":"data","col2":"data"}]
```

In any case, it's best not to do this by hand. Use a library to serialize your data.

Comment: I will be using ASP.NET and I can serialize DataTable to structure similar to suggested above. I am not sure about deserialization.

Comment: I'm sure ASP.NET has libraries to serialize XML and JSON. I'd be very surprised if Microsoft is still living in the dark ages. (come to think of it, I know they have libraries to handle XML because they're currently getting sued by a patent troll for it)

Answer (score 0):

You could return something like a [Fielded Text](http://www.fieldedtext.org/) value.  There sadly isn't a library to easily build such text objects in .Net but it's quite simple to implement it yourself and can definitely be parsed by any other platform.

By the way, do you really need to use a SOAP based web service?  It could perhaps simply be a text document returned when you call a given url.  Consider taking a look at a *RESTful* web service.